# Guardar resultado de Array en una variable PHP

Tags: php

Tengo una lista de productos que para mandar a JSON los pongo en un array pero me gustaría que todos los productos que se encontraron en el for se guardaran en una variable para después concatenar todo el resultado con otra variable.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
 for($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION["carrito"]);$i++){
    

    $producto= utf8_decode($_SESSION["carrito"];
    $cantidad= $_SESSION["mi_carrito"][$i]["cantidad"];
    $precio= $_SESSION["carrito"][$i]["precio"];
    $id_producto= $_SESSION["carrito"];
    
    
    $sql1="SELECT id_categoria FROM product WHERE id_product='$id_product'";
    $registros4=mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
    $fila4=mysqli_fetch_array($registros4);
    $id_categoria= $fila4;

          $datos= array(
         
    "itemNumber"  =>    $id_produc,
    "itemDescription" => $producto,
    "itemPrice"  => $precio,
    "itemQuantity" => $cantidad,
    "itemCategory"  => $id_categoria,

    );
    

    


//print_r ($datos );  // quisiera que cada vez que entra al for  se guardaran en una variable 
  
  
} ;
```

o que me recomendarían hacer?
Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de generar un array con los datos (que se pierden en cada iteración del for), se puede generar un array de arrays (2 dimensiones).

```
$datos[] = array(
    "itemNumber"  =>    $id_produc,
    "itemDescription" => $producto,
    "itemPrice"  => $precio,
    "itemQuantity" => $cantidad,
    "itemCategory"  => $id_categoria
)
```

La sintaxis `$variable[] = $valor` tiene el mismo efecto que usar `array_push($variable, $valor)`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu  ayuda , me ha funcionado .